# Проблемы с вызовом события при заполнении поля

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пробую сделать так чтобы вызывалась функция сразу после заполнения последнего поля. Пробывал функции `.bind` все работает, а с функцией `on` не получается. Вот код:

```js
$('input[name=name1]').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'Testdirect.php',
    data: $('.passegAdd').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $('#request').html(result);

    }
  });
  return true;

});
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
  <label class="nbox-span">Дата рождения</label>
  <input class="input_disable ntext-box" id="datarojdeni" name="name1" type="text" />
</div>
```

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как поправить проблему.

Comment: А #visiting_object что это?У поля атрибут readonly..

Comment: @Александр подредактировал код, убрал лишее

Comment: а что такое `passegAdd`? вы ж значение инпута не используете ни как

Comment: Лучше используйте blur,а после проверяйте и отправляйте свой Ajax